# Создание колонок по группам

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется следующая таблица:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'block': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
        'SCORE' : [131, 134, 34234, 5675, 67876, 6787]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

Необходимо создать колонки в зависимости от Block и заполнить их нужными значениями.

```
data = {'block': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
        'a_score' : [131, 134, 34234, 0, 0, 0],
        'b_score' : [0, 0, 0, 5675, 67876, 0],
        'c_score' : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6787]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

Следующий код выдает ошибку "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
if data['block'] == 'a':
    data = data.assign(a_score = data['SCORE'])
elif data['block'] == 'b':
    data = data.assign(b_score = data['SCORE'])
elif data['block'] == 'c':
    data = data.assign(c_score = data['SCORE'])
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
res = (data[["block"]]
       .join(pd.get_dummies(data["block"])
               .mul(data["score"], axis=0)
               .add_prefix("score_")))
```

результат:

```
In [178]: res
Out[178]:
  block  score_a  score_b  score_c
0     a      131        0        0
1     a      134        0        0
2     a    34234        0        0
3     b        0     5675        0
4     b        0    67876        0
5     c        0        0     6787
```

Comment: `get_dummies` в голову приходил, но что его можно скомбинировать в голову не пришло ))

Answer (score 2):

Можно например так. Наверняка можно и без цикла, но я что-то не соображу, это надо к MaxU, уважаемому:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'block': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
        'score' : [131, 134, 34234, 5675, 67876, 6787]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in data.block.unique():
    col = 'score_' + i
    data[col] = 0
    mask = data.block == i
    data.loc[mask, col] = data.loc[mask, 'score']

data = data.drop(columns='score')
data
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб, то вот так

```
data = {'block': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
        'score' : [131, 134, 34234, 5675, 67876, 6787]}
data["score_a"] = []
data["score_b"] = []
data["score_c"] = []
for i in range(len(data["block"])):
        if data["block"][i] == "a":
                data["score_a"].append(data["score"][i])
                data["score_b"].append(0)
                data["score_c"].append(0)
        elif data["block"][i] == "b":
                data["score_b"].append(data["score"][i])
                data["score_a"].append(0)
                data["score_c"].append(0)
        else:
                data["score_c"].append(data["score"][i])
                data["score_a"].append(0)
                data["score_b"].append(0)
for k,v in data.items():
        print(k,v)
```

Comment: а если не в лоб?)